# is there a python way to beep the system/motherboard speaker independent of the speakers attached to my computer?

Tags: python

I'm creating a python script to count the idle time in windows computer and it is write in a text file, so before the script runs i want to make beeb sound from system/motherboard speaker to make attention the the user to just move the mouse.
i wanted to make this because the user leave the shop for a while and come back i think this script is useful for me to check the idle time on the camera system to be sure that there is a person in shop or not. I'm new in Python
this is the code i get it through internet and edit on it to match my need.

```
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime

class LASTINPUTINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
      ('cbSize', ctypes.wintypes.UINT),
      ('dwTime', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
      ]

PLASTINPUTINFO = ctypes.POINTER(LASTINPUTINFO)


user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
GetLastInputInfo = user32.GetLastInputInfo
GetLastInputInfo.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
GetLastInputInfo.argtypes = [PLASTINPUTINFO]

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
GetTickCount = kernel32.GetTickCount
Sleep = kernel32.Sleep

def wait_until_idle(idle_time=60):
    idle_time_ms = int(idle_time*1000)
    liinfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    liinfo.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(liinfo)
    while True:
        GetLastInputInfo(ctypes.byref(liinfo))
        elapsed = GetTickCount() - liinfo.dwTime
        if elapsed>=idle_time_ms:
            break
        Sleep(idle_time_ms - elapsed or 1)


def wait_until_active(tol=5):
    liinfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    liinfo.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(liinfo)
    lasttime = None
    delay = 1 # ms
    maxdelay = int(tol*1000)
    while True:
        GetLastInputInfo(ctypes.byref(liinfo))
        if lasttime is None: lasttime = liinfo.dwTime
        if lasttime != liinfo.dwTime:
            break
        delay = min(2*delay, maxdelay)
        Sleep(delay)

def test():
    string = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p ')
    string2 = strftime('%A  %d-%b-%Y')
    new_line = '\n'
    #print("Waiting for 10 Second of no user input...")
    wait_until_idle(600)
    user32.MessageBeep(0)
    with open("D:\idle.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(new_line + string + string2 + ' Start')

   
test()
def test2():
    #print("Ok. Now, do something!")
    wait_until_active(1)
    user32.MessageBeep(0)
    now = datetime.now()
    string = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p ')
    string2 = now.strftime('%A  %d-%b-%Y')
    new_line = '\n'
    with open("D:\idle.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(new_line + string + string2 + ' End')

test2()

while True:
    duration1 = test()
    duration2 = test2()
    print(duration1)
    print(duration2)
```

Comment: yes. it's running but i need to add a code to make beeb sound from motherboard,
because if user mute the sound the motherboard sound still working

Comment: You *can* at least in theory tell Windows to associate a different sound output device with a given application.  Whether you can do that in practice depends on whether Windows sees the two devices as separate. That depends in turn (I think) on the sound card driver.

Comment: @MohamedHussein Had you mention that in your question?

Comment: yes, i did @Xitiz